# UIScrollView performance issues

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, uiscrollview, nsoperation

I am bundling up 2000 - 5000 images in uiscrollview with names. The current scrollview has quite hiccups during scrolling.

So the question is about how to improve performance. What I have searched so far is that I would have to get on NSOperations, NSQueue like things. But I'm not able to get any code sample on that. I remembered watching some video on WWDC 2010 on boosting performance of UItableview loading images being exhibited. Unfortunately I'm not able to remember that title too (worst perhaps it was 2009 video session).

So please can anyone point to me in right direction about what tutorial or sample code should I see. Atleast apple ios library reference links?

Comment: So you want to download images while scrolling down ah?

Comment: Images are bundled within app.I am not asking for downloading them over internet.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView uses lazy loading of reusable cells from a pool.

I'd advise you look at implementing something like this, so that only images objects that are actually viewed fetch an image.

NSOperations may be something you could look at to implement the actual fetch with but also consider using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to asynchronously grab them as this handles all the queuing and threading for you.

Comment: Images are not downloaded from web.Images are bundled within app.

Comment: If you are using [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:] or [UIImage initWithData:] this will be loading the image each time in memory...... maybe you should try using [UIImage imageNamed:]